# How to Generate Public key in DER format

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, der

What are the Steps to Generate

1)Public key in DER format
2)private key for signing the payload

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenSSL for this. public and private key naming as key pair.
Also you can use online free [services](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/rsa_key_generation/rsa_key_generation.php). 
[KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/) is desktop application with GUI also doing this.